# run jenkins pipeline agent with sudo

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have an Jenkins Server running in an docker container and have access to docker an the host system, so far it is working well. Now I want to set up a pipeline testing an script inside an docker container.

**Jenkinsfile:**

```
pipeline {
    agent { docker 'nginx:1.11' }
    stages {
        stage('build') {
            steps {
                sh 'nginx -t'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Error Message:**

```
> + docker pull nginx:1.11
> 
> Warning: failed to get default registry endpoint from daemon (Got
> permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket
> at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get
> http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.29/info: dial unix
> /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied). Using system
> default: https://index.docker.io/v1/
> 
> Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon
> socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post
> http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.29/images/create?fromImage=nginx&tag=1.11:
> dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
> 
> script returned exit code 1
```

My problem is that jenkins needs to run the docker command with sudo, but how to say the agent running the command with sudo?

Comment: Generally it is ok to run any command in docker without sudo. Have you tried it?

Comment: yes i tried the pipeline like above but I got an error message. The jenkins user is not added to docker users, so he need to use sudo. Maybe I could add the jenkins user to the docker group, but I prefer to run it with sudo... if it will be possible in pipeline

Comment: What is exactly the error message? What is your pipeline command? You should add them to the question

Comment: the command I write to the Jenkinsfile is the "pipeline{...}" command and I added the console output above. thanks for investing your time

Comment: Right now I only used freestyle jobs, so it was no problem to write "sudo docker pull nginx", in the freestyle jobs I also get an error message if I try to run docker without sudo.

Comment: Why do you prefer not to add `jenkins` user to the `docker` user group? Just curious.

Comment: I do it now, but I read that there could be a problem if host and container have not the same gid for docker group

Answer (score 32):

I have faced the same issue. After analysing the console log, I have found that the reason is that the Docker Jenkins Plugin starts a new container with a specific option **-u 107:112**:

```
...
docker run -t -d -u 107:112 ...
...
```

After trying many options such as: add `jenkins` to sudo group (it did not work because `jenkins` user does not exist in container), add `USER root` into `Dockerfile`, ... but none of them do the trick.

Finally I have found a solution that is using **args** in **docker agent** to overwrite the **-u** option. This is my **Jenkinsfile**:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'ubuntu'
            args '-u root:sudo -v $HOME/workspace/myproject:/myproject'
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage("setup_env") {
            steps {
                sh 'apt-get update -y'
                sh 'apt-get install -y git build-essential gcc cmake make'
            }
        }

        stage("install_dependencies") {
            steps {
                sh 'apt-get install -y libxml2-dev'
            }
        }
        stage("compile_dpi") {
            steps {
                sh 'cd /myproject && make clean && make -j4'
            }
        }

        stage("install_dpi") {
            steps {
                sh 'cd /myproject && make install'
            }
        }

        stage("test") {
            steps {
                sh 'do some test here'
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        success {
            echo 'Do something when it is successful'
            bitbucketStatusNotify(buildState: 'SUCCESSFUL')
        }
        failure {
            echo 'Do something when it is failed'
            bitbucketStatusNotify(buildState: 'FAILED')
        }
    }
}
```

There's maybe a security issue here but it is not the problem in my case.

Comment: If Jenkins is not running as root on the server, you're going run into issues because Jenkins will not be able to clear its workspace. When you do an `scm checkout`, it's done outside the container and jenkins uses that `-u` to map its own user into the container. If you build a project, those files will be root on the local system and Jenkins will fail subsequent builds.

Comment: thank you @luongnv89, fixed my problems very well except the -u option should be "root:root" instead of "root:sudo"

Comment: @djsumdog, thanks for your pointing out. Currently I will use luongnv89's solution to work around my problems, and hope I will not meet the problems you mentioned above...

Comment: This code worked for me in fedora docker . after applying below argument as  args '-u root:root'   . no need -v (mount the volume) automatically docker pipeline mounting the volume

Comment: I just needed to support apt-get, so I just added `args '-u root:root'`  and everything else kept working.

Answer (score 5):

As others have suggested, the issue is that jenkins does not have permission to run docker containers. Let's go over the ways you could launch jenkins first, and then see what could be done in each of these ways.

#### 1. running jenkins manually

Surely you could download & run jenkins with java as suggested [in here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/linux/). In this method, you could do several things to allow your jenkins user to use docker:

###### a. give jenkins user root access:

I do not suggest this way, after all you are giving your pipelines access to everything! So you probably do not want this to happen.

###### b. add jenkins user to docker group

Like explained [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/) you could manage docker as non-root user. just add your user to  docker group and thats all. I recommend it if you know who is going to use docker (cause well, you are giving him root access in docker in a way).

###### c. make docker rootless

This is a new feature docker added to its arsenal recently. You could read in detail what it implies [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/). To tell you the truth I am not a fan of this feature! The reason is that you can not (at least I could not find a way) to make it work for a user in a container (as you need to stop docker service to make it happen), also I had some difficulties configing dns when using rootless mode. But it should be fine if you are not in a container.

#### 2. running jenkins in docker

This method is more troublesome actually! I struggled with the ways I could use docker in jenkins container, but in the end got the results needed, so was worth the effort.

To run docker in jenkins (which is also a docker container itself) you have three ways:

###### 1. use dind (docker in docker)

It is pretty straight forward, you run dind image & connect docker in jenkins container to the dind, without any special permission handling you can use docker at will.

###### 2. use dood (docker outside of docker)

mount docker path as a volume in the docker run script for your jenkins, **note** that you need to use one of the two ways I explained above (in running jenkins manually) to be able to use docker, it could be a bit tricky but possible.

###### 3. run agent as a docker in a different environment & connect remote agent in jenkins

At last it is possible to run the agent separately & connecting the remote agent in jenkins. Although this does not exactly answer your question, but is a way you could use.

These ways for just running a docker in jenkins, you will probably have some issues after you ran a docker as agent, like having permission issues in the agent container itself, which is most likely because of the agent's user (if you like, you could access the user with command

```
docker exec -it [agent container id] whoami
```

e.g. in this sample the user in agent is **node**

```
agent { 
  docker { image 'node:14-alpine' } 
}

steps{
  sh 'npm i -g random'
}
```

so it would throw an error because the node user does not have permission to install npm module globally (I know, it is weird!)

so as [luongnv89](https://stackoverflow.com/users/822335/luongnv89) mentioned, you could change the user running the docker like this

```
agent { 
  docker { image 'node:14-alpine' args '-u root' } 
}
```

Hope this was helpful understanding the whole picture.

Comment: agent { 
  docker { image 'node:14-alpine' args '-u root' } 
}

solved my issues. thanks

Comment: For option 1b - you'll have to restart jenkins after. You can visit (jenkins_url)/restart to restart jenkins manually from the browser

Answer (score 4):

I'd solve the problem differently, matching the jenkins group id inside the container to that of the docker socket you've mounted a volume. I do this with an entrypoint that runs as root, looks up the gid of the socket, and if that doesn't match that of the gid inside the current container, it does a `groupmod` to correct it inside the container. Then I drop privileges to the `jenkins` user to launch Jenkins. This entrypoint run on every startup, but fairly transparently to the Jenkins app that is launched.

All the steps to perform this are included in this github repo: https://github.com/sudo-bmitch/jenkins-docker/

Answer (score 3):

You can work around that by:

1- In your `Dockerfile` add jenkins to the sudoers file:

`RUN echo "jenkins ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers`

2- Add an extra step in your `Jenkinsfile` to give jenkins the right permissions to use docker:

```
pipeline {

    agent none

    stages {

        stage("Fix the permission issue") {

            agent any

            steps {
                sh "sudo chown root:jenkins /run/docker.sock"
            }

        }

        stage('Step 1') {

            agent {
                docker {
                    image 'nezarfadle/tools'
                    reuseNode true
                }
            }

            steps {
                sh "ls /"
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: By allowing jenkins to sudo ALL:ALL, you are essentially turning him into a proxy-root user. I would strongly recommend against this, unless your build-pipeline and the user, and the jenkins webserver are all sufficiently secured to allow this level of trust.

Comment: That step with `sh "sudo chown root:jenkins /run/docker.sock"` fixed my problems. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was

```
node() {
    String jenkinsUserId = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'id -u jenkins').trim()
    String dockerGroupId = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'getent group docker | cut -d: -f3').trim()
    String containerUserMapping = "-u $jenkinsUserId:$dockerGroupId "
    docker.image('image')
        .inside(containerUserMapping + ' -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro') {
             sh "..."
         }
}
```

This way the user in the container still uses the jenkins user id + group id to avoid permissions conflicts with shared data but is also member of the docker group inside container which is required to access the docker socket (/var/run/docker.sock)

I prefer this solution as it doesn't require any additional scripts or dockerfiles

Comment: This is a scripted pipeline, right? Does this work under declarative pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same exact issue. You need to add jenkins user to docker group:

```
DOCKER_SOCKET=/var/run/docker.sock
DOCKER_GROUP=docker
JENKINS_USER=jenkins

if [ -S ${DOCKER_SOCKET} ]; then
DOCKER_GID=$(stat -c '%g' ${DOCKER_SOCKET})
sudo groupadd -for -g ${DOCKER_GID} ${DOCKER_GROUP}
sudo usermod -aG ${DOCKER_GROUP} ${JENKINS_USER}
fi

# Start Jenkins service
sudo service jenkins restart
```

After you run the above, pipelines successfully start docker

Answer (score 1):

I might have found a reasonably good solution for this.

## Setup

I run Jenkins as a container and use it to build containers on the dockerhost it's running on. To do this, I pass `/var/run/docker.sock` as a volume to the container.

**Just to reiterate the disclaimer some other people already stated: Giving access to the docker socket is essentially like giving root access to the machine - be careful!**

I assume that you've already installed docker into your Jenkins Image.

## Solution

This is based on the fact, that the docker binary is not in the first directory of `$PATH`. We basically place a shell script that runs `sudo docker` instead of just the plain `docker` command (and passes the parameters along).

Add a file like this to your jenkins repository and call it `docker_sudo_overwrite.sh`:

```
#! /bin/sh 
# This basically is a workaround to add sudo to the docker command, because aliases don't seem to work 
# To be honest, this is a horrible workaround that depends on the order in $PATH
# This file needs to be place in /usr/local/bin with execute permissions
sudo /usr/bin/docker $@
```

Then extend your Jenkins `Dockerfile` like this:

```
# Now we need to allow jenkins to run docker commands! (This is not elegant, but at least it's semi-portable...)
USER root

## allowing jenkins user to run docker without specifying a password
RUN echo "jenkins ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/docker" >> /etc/sudoers

# Create our alias file that allows us to use docker as sudo without writing sudo
COPY docker_sudo_overwrite.sh /usr/local/bin/docker
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker

# switch back to the jenkins-user
USER jenkins
```

This gives the jenkins service user the ability to run the docker binary as root with sudo (without providing a password). Then we copy our script to `/usr/local/bin/docker` which "overlays" the actual binary and runs it with `sudo`. If it helps, you can look at my example on [Github](https://github.com/MauriceBrg/docker-buildpipeline/tree/master/jenkins).

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here where.

```
[...]
agent { docker 'whatever_I_try_doesnt_work'} # sudo, jenkins user in dockerroot group etc
[...]
```

So my workaround is to add it as one of the steps in the the build stage of the pipeline as follow:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'sudo docker pull python:3.5.1'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I also think about this, but then streps are not running inside the container. So it is not the same. it is ok to download or start a container, but much more complicate if you want to run commands inside the script.