# Jenkins declarative pipeline: infer docker args from shell command

Tags: linux, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins job that currently runs on Linux inside a container, but as the `root` user. I tried making it build as the `jenkins` user, but there's a wrinkle: the job needs to create some docker containers, so it needs to run some `docker build` and `docker save` commands. The jenkins user is part of the Docker group on our build host. Simply mounting the Docker socket in the container won't work by itself because, not sure why, the jenkins user only inherits one primary group inside the container:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            label '<label>'
            image '<image>:latest'
            args '--privileged  --network host -v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd -v /etc/group:/etc/group -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'
        }
    }
```

I'm mapping the `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` files from the host in the container so as not to bother with creating users and groups in the container.

With this Jenkinsfile, `docker build` fails because it can't access the UNIX socket:

```
+ docker build -t <tag> .
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: [...]
```

So I've tried adding `-u jenkins:docker`  to the docker command line, but that also doesn't work - Docker complains about not finding the jenkins user:

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to run image '<image>:latest'. Error: docker: Error response from daemon: unable to find user jenkins: no matching entries in passwd file.
```

So I'm guessing the user / group has to exist in Docker, otherwise we have to supply the uid/gid. I've verified that using the hard-coded uid/gid in args works, e.g.:

```
            args '-u 1001:1002 --privileged  --network host -v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd -v /etc/group:/etc/group -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'
```

Now, I don't like hard-coding the ids, because if using multiple build hosts, the ids might not match. So I think I need something like this:

```
            args '-u $(id -u):$(getent group docker | cut -d: -f3) --privileged  --network host -v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd -v /etc/group:/etc/group -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'
```

However, this won't work:

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to run image '<image>:latest'. Error: Unable to find image 'group:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for group, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.
```

I guess running shell commands in the `args` does not work, something weird happens instead of the expected shell expansion.

Is it possible to do this with Declarative pipeline? By 'this' meaning using the result of shell commands in docker args? I've seen one example for this in another stackoverflow item (here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54456263/1654721), but that's with scripted pipeline, so not helpful in my case.

Comment: Try implementing this with the Docker Pipeline plugin: https://plugins.jenkins.io/docker-workflow/. It would be easier, and the global variable methods return useable objects (which you claim to need).

Comment: Isn't that plugin meant for scripted pipelines? I've seen examples like that in the "using Docker with pipeline" section of the user handbook, but all of them seem to pertain to scripted (not declarative) pipeline. See https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#advanced-usage-with-scripted-pipeline.

Comment: Yes, it is also compatible with scripted pipelines.

Comment: OK, let me clarify: I don't see any example there using the declarative pipeline syntax (https://www.theserverside.com/answer/Declarative-vs-scripted-pipelines-Whats-the-difference). My Jenkinsfile uses the declarative syntax, which seems to be what's recommended nowadays, so I'm looking for solutions applicable to that.

Comment: Somewhat related Jenkins bug (touching on ability to use variables in docker args): https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-42369. Interesting workaround for the variables problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53923775/1654721